# most interesting or the most interesting

Tags: superlatives, intensifiers

a. Most interesting was what we saw on the fifth day of our stay in Paris.

b. What was most interesting was what we saw on the fifth day of our stay in Paris.

c. What we saw on the fifth day of our stay in Paris was most interesting.

In which case:

1. 'Most' means 'extremely

and in which case:

2. We have a real superlative

---

Can one say

a. **The** most interesting was what we saw on the fifth day of our stay in Paris.

b. What was **the** most interesting was what we saw on the fifth day of our stay in Paris.

c. What we saw on the fifth day of our stay in Paris was **the** most interesting.

?

Many thanks.

Comment: Either one of several "interesting sights" (use *the*) or your opinion of that sight (no *the*). It is your choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My vote is for, **'The most interesting (thing/of all) was what we saw on the fifth day of our stay in Paris'** 
**The most interesting of all was what we saw on the fifth day of our stay in --Paris** This sounds good. But, you need to say what was it in the following sentence. The sentence has a feel that some thing is yet to be revealed.

Comment: Yeah, without knowing what the noun is, the second set of sentences sounds awkward.

Answer (score 2):

> Most interesting was what we saw on the fifth day of our stay in Paris.

*To be* is a copular verb that can link adjectives/adjective phrases to nouns/noun phrases.  So *interesting* is an adjective and doesn't need an article.  Doing this requires context so the listener/reader knows the type of thing that would be interesting.

When you try:

> The most interesting was what we saw on the fifth day of our stay in Paris.

Here you are "noun-ifying" an adjective.  You could only really get away with this if you say directly what the interesting thing was.  Doing this also really requires previous context so that the question "the most interesting [what?]" is answerable without a lot of thought.

> I was looking at vehicles.  The most interesting was the vintage blue car.